# JavaScript send JSON POST request to Mattermost incoming webhook

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-post, mattermost

I am new to Javascript , currently writing up a script which sending some string as JSON to Mattermost incoming hook(Mattermost only accept JSON data) . I've tested it with curl , it works without any issues, the command is below :

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"text": "Hello, this is some text\nThis is more text. :tada:"}'http://mattermost.test.nz/hooks/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

This is the script that I wrote, it's not sending the data to the endpoint for some reason, I've tried to figure it out myself but it's just not working . Please can anyone help..

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://mattermost.test.nz/hooks/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var data = {"test"};
xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: In the first query, it seems that you are sending something like {text:"myText"}, and on the second only {"myText"}. Do you have the server's log and the information status of the request ?

Comment: The first command just an example, I am using that command as a test and it works. Mattermost only support  JSON

Comment: Yes, but why on the second example you don't send the same json structure ? And could you show us the response from the server ?

Comment: Why is this tagged with Alfresco?

Comment: as this script will be run on Alfresco server , and I not sure if this is the right way to do it